# Convert Javascript Array Within JSON Object Into Postgresql VARCHAR Array

Tags: postgresql

**For mods** I've spent around 30 minutes researching SO and Google to try and find a solution to this, so I can't be alone. Hoping this serves as a useful question for others in the future.

I am passing the following JSON object into a postgresql function:

```
{
  "jsarray" : ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
}
```

And, within my table, I have a column called convertedelement that is a `VARCHAR[]`.

I want that column to be replaced with the js-style array passed in.

I.E.

```
["item1","item2","item3"] --> {item1,item2,item3}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic function that accomplishes this, modify as needed!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION updatecontact(myobject JSON)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE mytable AS c
    SET 
        yourcolumnname = ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text((myobject->>'yourjsonkeyname')::JSONB))
    WHERE yourcondition = whateveryouwant;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will result in a `json` object with an array like so `["item1","item2","item3"]` being converted and added to a varchar column of your choice as `{item1,item2,item3}`